# How to Change Colors of Node Terminal Output?

Tags: debugging, logging

When I run a node template with `cargo run -r -- --dev` I get a whole bunch of debug info in the terminal.
Is it possible to change colors of some words (phrases) in the terminal output? For example: color of `best` and `finalized` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell
It is quite likely you just want to highlight within the terminal when operating.

I you want to build this *into* your node's logic, read on.

To start, the [`log` crate](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.17/log/) is used in AFAIK all places `stdout/stderr` logging is enabled in Substrate. Substrate provides a minimal Wasm ready logger implementation: [`runtime_logger`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/runtime/src/runtime_logger.rs) that is used in the runtime API [described here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/api/src/lib.rs#L44-L54).

But the meat of your question relates to the [logging crates, specifically `EventFormat.enable_color`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/tracing/src/logging/event_format.rs#L42-L43) and the associated logic that stems from it. See the [`/client/tracing/src/logging/*` implementation in Substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/tracing/src/logging/event_format.rs#L166-L175) for trace-level logging color schmeme.

For a *custom logger* that had such nuanced coloring built in, IIUC you would need to implement this are replace the present logic. Perhaps as stated to start, you simply want to *highlight keywords* rather than chage logic o the node.