# How to print color log in terminal with no_std requirement?

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, log, precompile

I tried to use ansi_term to print logs because it is used in the Substrate repository for logging:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fece0657f20e15df94be5833b164dfacd44823eb/client/informant/src/lib.rs
which is mentioned also in [How to Change Colors of Node Terminal Output?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/how-to-change-colors-of-node-terminal-output)

```
use ansi_term::Colour;
...
 info!("♻️  Reorg on #{},{} to #{},{}, common ancestor #{},{}",
                        Colour::Red.bold().paint(format!("{}", last_num)),...);
```

then I found `ansi_term` cannot be used in my parachain precompile because my runtime must support `no_std` as I see `#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]` in the beginning of my precompile lib.rs file.

Substrate docs does not say much about color logs:
https://docs.substrate.io/test/debug/

I am aware of using `log::warn!()` and `log::error!()` AND running your parachain with `--execution Native` can produce a tiny colorful log in yellow and red... but that is not really enough.

So how can I make colorful logs and support `no_std`?

Comment: Actually, I don't recommend you to use that for the log. Some log are pretty long, the output might be truncated if you force it to use color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the color code directly.

Those crates just made a wrapper for the color code.

---

Check:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences
- https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2020/03/28/terminal-colors.html

---

Example:

```rust
fn main() {
    // you could replace `println!` with `log::info!` in no_std
    println!("\u{1b}[35mtest\u{001b}[0ming");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. thank you :)

Comment: this one is easy to use: https://github.com/rust-osdev/ansi_rgb